# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, django-guardian, django-userena

After I install Django-userena,there is an error
my django version :1.9.5
I just install django-userena step by step ,but when i migrate it ,an error happend and I don't how to solve it.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 50, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\guardian\management\__init__.py", line 33, in create_anonymous_user
    User.objects.get(**lookup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 381, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'userena',
    'guardian',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'accounts',    
]
```

Comment: It looks like the application `guardian` queries the ORM in a situation where the DB is not available yet. That's a bug, you should report it.

Answer (score 14):

```
./manage.py migrate
```

if your Django version is 1.9 or lower, use

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

then

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

more details on https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

May it help

Answer (score 7):

```
  python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

This command will look into which tables were not created and will create all the needed tables.

Comment: You're welcome, i'm happy that my comment was useful.

Comment: the underrated solution, I was getting crazy, thank you.

Comment: @SalahRashad You're welcome! I'm happy that my comment is still useful.

Answer (score 6):

I was get same error and to fix the same, I checked if the mentioned table in error is present in connected DB or not. It was not. Applied migration again  and it worked.

```
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\guardian\management\__init__.py", line 33, in create_anonymous_user
    User.objects.get(**lookup)`

`guardian\management\__init__.py` is calling `User` before it is defined.

Why is it called before it is defined?
...well, it is called by `makemigrations` to find out if there are changes in the `db` to define them (the changes that are found)

...so this is a "chicken and egg" problem.

I have the same error with a similar problem but the offending code was my own code (not a library like `guardian`)

My code was like this:

`CHAT_BOT_USER, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username='rosty', \ email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER)`

The offending part is the `User` being used before the `auth_user` table is created

I solved by only executing the code when the table is present. This happens when there is no `OperationError`. And you can know it with a `try/except` like this:

```
from django.db import OperationalError

try:
    CHAT_BOT_USER, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username='rosty', email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER)

except OperationalError:
    CHAT_BOT_USER = None

if created:
    CHAT_BOT_USER.set_password(settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
    CHAT_BOT_USER.save()
```

This way `makemigrations` runs the `except` code and `runserver` runs the `try` code.

Note the `created` boolean, you may use any other way to avoid `makemigration` run code that depends on the `User.objects....` results

Answer (score 0):

RUN: python3 manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

I have came across same error while working with chatrooms.
I resolved using deleting the **db.sqlite3** file and deleting the **0001_initial.py** file in the migrations folder of the app and then i executed the following statements:-

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

then i was able to create a superuser using

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Thats it error resolved!

Answer (score 0):

This occurs whenever the tables are not created, or the tables are not available in the database to which this application is pointed in `settings.py`.

So create the migration files by using this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

After the migration files are created, you need to migrate them:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If it doesn't work then use:

```
python manage.py makemigrations yourappname
python manage.py migrate yourappname
```